# Is it right to return validation error (400) on GET request in REST application?

Tags: rest

I am building REST application and I need to implement filtering by GET parameters. For example filter objects with some particular type:

```
example.com/api/objects/?type=some_type
```

Question:

What REST endpoint should return if inputed type is incorrect?

Example: endpoint receives request

```
example.com/api/objects/?type=other_type
```

and `other_type` is not allowed type for `object`.

What error code I have to return?

(My versions:

400 - because input was not valid, but it is strange - return 400 error on GET request.

422 - I am not sure that this is logical error

Return empty response.
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 400 Bad Request is correct, however if you response proper error message like the following, it would be very usefull

```
{
   "code": <your error code>,
   "validation": 

   {
      "exception": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing type"
    },
   "message": "Validation faild"
    "request" : "example.com/api/objects/?type=other_type"
}
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation why code 400 is right? (Some links or explain it by yourself).

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html  10.4.1 400 Bad Request

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.